# Pyodide Plotly out of memory, memory access out of bounds

Tags: javascript, python, console, plotly, pyodide

I've faced some interesting issue.

The problem is when I run the code snippet with pyodide and **console is opened** it works properly:

```
import pandas
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(
df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length",
color="species")
    
fig
```

[image]

Otherwise when I try to run the same code snippet and **console is closed**, it gets broken then these logs appear (if I open a console when everything's broken):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Chrome, it's very likely a bug in Chrome 89 - 90, which should be fixed in Chrome 91.

For more details see: pyodide#1507 and bugs.chromium.org#1200031